# Apollo GraphQL Client (ReactJS) - Accessing props in graphql query

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I have a component that shows all users tied to a specific type of entity. The component renders with the apollo graphql [compose](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo.html#compose) helper. The export of the component looks like this:

```
export const UsersContainer = compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
    graphql(gql`
        query manager($id: Int!) {
          manager(id: $id) {
            users {
              id
              firstName
              lastName
              email
              username
            }
          }
        }`, {
    options: (props) => ({
        variables: {
            id: props.currentOrg.org.id
        }
    }),
})
)(Users);
```

This all works fine. The issue I'm facing is that I want to make this component dynamic so it will work with all entity types (ie. `manager`, `client`, `vendor`). So, in the above query: `query manager($id: Int!)` would change to: `query client($id: Int!)`, and so forth.

How can I access the redux store to pull in data to dynamically build the `gql` query? The data is all available in the store. I just need a way to access the props in a way that I can dynamically build the gql query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You effectively need to define three different queries and then conditionally switch between them. The problem is the `graphql` HOC doesn't provide an easy way to derive which query to use from props. This is probably easiest to do with the new `Query` component, which uses the render props pattern:

```
const QueryA = gql`query { # blah }`
const QueryB = gql`query { # blah }`

const WrapperComponent = props => {
  const query = props.foo ? QueryA: QueryB
  return (
    <Query query={query}>
      {({loading, error, data}) => (
        <YourComponent/>
      )}
    </Query>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ foo }) => ({ foo })
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(WrapperComponent)
```

Using the HOC, you could do something like:

```
const QueryA = gql`query { # blah }`
const QueryB = gql`query { # blah }`

const QueryAComponent = graphql(QueryA)(YourComponent)
const QueryBComponent = graphql(QueryB)(YourComponent)

const WrapperComponent = props => (
  props.foo
  ? QueryAComponent
  : QueryBComponent
)

const mapStateToProps = ({ foo }) => ({ foo })
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(WrapperComponent)
```

If you're going the HOC route, you could also use something like recompose's [branch](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#branch) to conditionally render the components.